# How to execute this query in postgresql database i was in trouble to execute that

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

How to solve this error, I was in trouble to run that query is anyone please help to execute that query with all the attributes.

PG_QUERY:-

```
UPDATE mapschema_127_17.layertable_2156_17 AS a 
SET "area(sqkm)" = newvalues.area(sqkm),
    "county" = newvalues.county,
    "countyfp" = newvalues.countyfp,
    "geoid" = newvalues.geoid,
    "gid" = newvalues.gid,
    "land(sqm)" = newvalues.land(sqm),
    "state" = newvalues.state,
    "statefp" = newvalues.statefp,
    "stusps" = newvalues.stusps,
    "water(sqm)" = newvalues.water(sqm) 
FROM 
    (VALUES ('2813.807491', 'Rich County', '033', '49033', 1, '2664700959', 'Utah', '49', 'UT', '149106532'),
            ('3037.725199', 'Cache County', '005', '49005', 2, '3016627502', 'Utah', '49', 'UT', '21097697'),
            ('8418.300607', 'Duchesne County', '013', '49013', 3, '8379502802', 'Utah', '49', 'UT', '38797805'),
            ('9543.91397', 'Grand County', '019', '49019', 28, '9512361692', 'Utah', '49', 'UT', '31552278'),
            ('18870.630612', 'Tooele County', '045', '49045', 29, '17979556898', 'Utah', '49', 'UT', '891073714')) AS newvalues ("area(sqkm)", "county", "countyfp", "geoid", "gid", "land(sqm)", "state", "statefp", "stusps", "water(sqm)") 
WHERE a.gid = newvalues.gid
```

Error:

> ERROR: column "sqkm" does not exist LINE 1: ...able_2156_17 as a SET
> "area(sqkm)"=newvalues.area(sqkm),"cou... ^

Where `area(sqkm)` is a column name with double precision data type.

Comment: Does the column `sqkm`exist in the table `mapschema_127_17.layertable_2156_17`?

Comment: The column name is `area(sqkm)` and it is exist in the table `mapschema_127_17.layertable_2156_17` @JimJones

Comment: That's a very "unorthodox" column name :) Could you add the `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Comment: @JimJones i add this table using `shp2pgsql`

Comment: While these column names are very readable, you are forced to use quotes on them in every query. I consider it a good idea to include the unit in the column names so as to avoid semantic errors, but names like `area_sqkm` instead of `"area(sqkm)"` could make your life easier :-)

Comment: And then don't make everything a string. I suppose that `'2813.807491', 'Rich County', '033', '49033', 1, '2664700959', 'Utah', '49', 'UT', '149106532'` is supposed to be `2813.807491, 'Rich County', '033', 49033, 1, 2664700959, 'Utah', 49, 'UT', 149106532`? Or are all these columns really strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of special characters in object names is allowed - by means of wrapping it up with quotes `"` -, but quite often it leads to confusion. This example with very strange column names might make things clearer:

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=13f6dedf4c95ab816a17a93b9a46b7d2)

```
CREATE TABLE t ("(id)" int, "#(txt)" text);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1,'foo');

UPDATE t SET "#(txt)" = newvalues."#(txt)"
FROM (VALUES (1,'bar')) newvalues ("(id)","#(txt)")
WHERE t."(id)" = newvalues."(id)";

SELECT * FROM t;

 (id) | #(txt) 
------+--------
    1 | bar
```

This should fix your query:

```
UPDATE mapschema_127_17.layertable_2156_17 AS a 
SET "area(sqkm)"=newvalues."area(sqkm)",
    "county"=newvalues."county",
    "countyfp"=newvalues."countyfp",
    "geoid"=newvalues."geoid",
    "gid"=newvalues."gid",
    "land(sqm)"=newvalues."land(sqm)",
    "state"=newvalues."state",
    "statefp"=newvalues."statefp",
    "stusps"=newvalues."stusps",
    "water(sqm)"=newvalues."water(sqm)" 
FROM 
  (VALUES 
    (2813.807491,'Rich County','033','49033',1,'2664700959','Utah','49','UT','149106532'),
    (3037.725199,'Cache County','005','49005',2,'3016627502','Utah','49','UT','21097697'),
    (8418.300607,'Duchesne County','013','49013',3,'8379502802','Utah','49','UT','38797805'),
    (9543.91397,'Grand County','019','49019',28,'9512361692','Utah','49','UT','31552278'),
    (18870.630612,'Tooele County','045','49045',29,'17979556898','Utah','49','UT','891073714')) AS newvalues ("area(sqkm)","county","countyfp","geoid","gid","land(sqm)","state","statefp","stusps","water(sqm)") 
WHERE a."gid" = newvalues."gid";
```

Comment: I try this but i got this error-
`ERROR:  column "area(sqkm)" is of type double precision but expression is of type text
LINE 5: SET "area(sqkm)"=newvalues."area(sqkm)",`

Comment: @Ayush that's a totally different issue. You're inserting a `text` in a `double precision` column.. and it is not allowed. Can you add the `create table` statement?

Comment: @Ayush I just edited the query with the modification of `"area(sqkm)" `.

Comment: I tried this  with `column data type text ` and it works, But it doesn't work with my data, can you please suggest something that i can work with `double precision` or some other data types also with this query.

Comment: @Ayush have you tried my last edit? I removed the `'` single quotes around the values of `"area(sqkm)"`

Comment: Thank you its working now. with removing `'` from the other data type columns value.